# need example shows difference between directed set and full directed set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory, order-theory

we know that A Set $S$ together with a relation $\ge$ which is both $transitive$ and $reflexive$ such that for any two elements **a**,**b** in $S$, there exists another element **c** in $S$ with **c** $\ge$ **a** and **c** $\ge$ **b** In this case, the relation $\ge$ is said to "direct" the set.

But can we  call A Set $S$ is A **FULL directed** Set : *If*  **Every** subset From $S$ is a directed Set?

I need an example of a directed set but it is not A **Full** directed one.

Comment: It seems like a full directed set is necessarily a chain.

Comment: after search  yeb it is a chain  
can you help me with an example

Comment: Well, in that case, any directed set that is not a chain will be an example

Comment: Would this work? $S=P\bigl(\{0,1\}\bigr)=\bigl\{\emptyset,\{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\bigr\}$ with the inclusion as the transitive and reflexive relation. $S$ is clearly directed (the union plays the role of the join). Then the subset $\bigl\{\{0\},\{1\}\bigr\}$ of $S$ is not directed.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That would work. And without the empty set, it would work too (this would be the minimal example)

Comment: @amrsa: yep, without $\emptyset$ it works too, and is very likely the minimal example.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf Up to isomorphism, it is the minimal example. It must have two non comparable elements to have a non directed subset, and it must have an element greater than those two...

Comment: thanks alot .. it is just i am so  beginner in those stuff

Comment: Mauy I ask  If we have a directed Set $S$ that (in addition ) satisfy for any two elements **a**,**b** in $S$, there exists another element **d** in $S$ with d $\le$ a and d $\le$ b In this case  what can we call the Set $S$?
@gniourf_gniourf

Comment: if you can help my friend @amrsa

Comment: Sometimes, to distinguish the situations, what above is called a directed set, is also called an *up-directed set* (upward directed set, upwardly directed set). The situation you asked about (1 hour ago) is then called a *down-directed set* (downward directed set, downwardly directed set). See [the Wikipedia article on directed sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_set).

Comment: thanks alot ... what if we have a set $S$ that is a  (  upward directed set **AND** downward directed set ) At the **Same** time, what can we call S in  this situation?
@amrsa

Comment: I don't know of any specific name for that. If in a document you deal a lot with these three concepts, I would suggest that you define a directed set as one which is both up-directed and down-directed. But that definition should stand out very clearly, since it is customary (perhaps for historical reasons) to call directed sets to those which are up-directed.